# SQL: department name with minimum of 10 employees

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for employees and another for department names. 
The constructions are

employees
- employee_id
- employee_name
- department_id

departments
 - department_id
 - department_name

I want to show a table with department names where more than 10 employees work.

The query I tried without results is:

```
select count(*) as count,d.department_name
from employees e
inner join departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id 
where count(*) > 5
group by d.department_name
```

please suggest correction

Comment: Do you want "minimum of 10 employees", or "more than 10 employees"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific clause that occurs after group by for this, the `HAVING` clause, that allows filtering on aggregated values.

```
select count(*) as count,d.department_name
from employees e
inner join departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id 
group by d.department_name
HAVING count(*) > 10
```

NB: The where clause should continue to be used for conditions that do not rely on aggregates. e.g. if you just wanted "sales related" departments

```
select count(*) as count,d.department_name
from employees e
inner join departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id 
WHERE d.department_name like 'sales%'
group by d.department_name
HAVING count(*) > 10
```

Comment: There's a convention whereby the table against which a where condition is imposed appears first in the select. It's not a rule, just a sort of tradition, I suppose.

Comment: @Strawberry I was using a phone at the time and it was getting all too hard to tidy up to that extent.